# cocos2d-x 3 batch drawing explained

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, batch-drawing

I have read [this page](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Texture_Cache) to understand batch drawing details, but I still have questions. I know that in order to reduce draw call number we need to use batch drawing. I use it like this:

```
auto spritebatch = SpriteBatchNode::create("ingame.png");
SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("ingame.plist");
```

And now I need to create a Sprite I have to do this:

```
auto backgroundSprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("back_gradient.png");
spritebatch->addChild(backgroundSprite);
```

But I don't understand the following things:

1. What if my game has several spritesheets. For example I have HUD spritesheet and ingame spritesheet. Now if I want to show ingame screen with HUD then I need to create 2 `SpriteBatchNode`? and add them into ingame layer?
2. What if the same spritesheet should be used in different Scenes. Should I do the following again?

   auto spritebatch = SpriteBatchNode::create("ingame.png");
   SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("ingame.plist");
3. What if I use sprites with `Button`, `TextEdit`, `Label` and other UI elements.

   - First of all can I initialize Button state images from spritesheet?
   - As I know I cannot add UI element as a child to `SpriteBatchNode`. In this case how to combile UI elements and sprite in the same view/scene?

Sorry for lots of questions. But the fact is that I could not find any resource that contains the explanations to this questions. While they are all related. If you don't know answers to these questions, you don't know how to use `SpriteBatchNode`.

Comment: There is no need to use `SpriteBatchNode` in cocos2d-x version 3+.

Comment: @GameDeveloper But there is! You reduce draw calls. If you have 7 different images, on the screen as sprite then you have 7 draw calls, whereas, if you use a spritsheet you have only one draw call for 7 different images. You don't need only if you draw the same image multiple times, because after the first time it is in the cache already.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CCSpriteBatchNode in cocos2d-x v3. Batching is automatic and best left to the renderer to optimize draw calls through batch drawing. It says so right in the article you've linked:

> The Render graph was decoupled from the Scene graph.That means that auto-batching is supported, finally :-) And the new renderer is so fast, that we no longer encourage the use of SpriteBatchNode.

Comment: My conclusion about this is as follows: I should use spritsheet to cache whole set of images, also for creating animations, but I don't need to use batch node. Batching is being done automatically. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree, depending not how fast new render is we want to get most of it as we can.

Narek, you are correct.
During rendering the geometry will be sorted to reduce the quantity of GL calls. But don't expect it will sort children of different parents in one line. Example: you have

Node **A** with children **ab** and **ac**

Node **B** with children **bd** and **be**.

if b and d uses textures of same atlas it is not guaranted you will get any perfomance boost of using atlases at all.

But I can confirm, currently it is really fast, and at my case the GL calls are not the bottleneck at all :)